# Supervisord to send slack notification when a process starts

Tags: supervisord, slack

I am looking to add a web hook to a supervisord file.

// sys admin skills are less then present...

current file..

```
[supervisord]
user=root
nodaemon=true
logfile=/role/log/supervisord.log
```

Original approach would be to make it run a shell script, however, I am unsure how to pull what process is being started...

Answer (score 0):

Define an [event listener](http://supervisord.org/events.html#configuring-an-event-listener) that triggers on `PROCESS_STATE_STARTING`. Then you can write a simplified event listener (see [the example](http://supervisord.org/events.html#example-event-listener-implementation)) to actually perform the Slack notification.

An event listener configuration might look like this:

```
[eventlistener:slack]
command=slack_listener.py
events=PROCESS_STATE_STARTING
```